# Proving $\int_a^{b}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{a^2b^2(1+x)^2+({a+b})^2}\ dx=\frac{\ln (a+b)-\ln (ab)}{ab(a+b)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How can I prove this?
> $$\int_a^{b}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{a^2b^2(1+x)^2+({a+b})^2}\ dx=\frac{\ln (a+b)-\ln (ab)}{ab(a+b)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

Here is my attempt

$$ \frac{1}{a^2b^2}\int_a^{b}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{(1+x)^2+(\frac{a+b}{ab})^2}\ dx$$

Applying the substitution $1+x=t \left (\dfrac{a+b}{ab}\right )$

$$ \frac{\frac{a+b}{ab}}{a^2b^2(\frac{a+b}{ab})^2}\int_{\frac{ab(a+1)}{a+b}}^{\frac{ab(b+1)}{a+b}}\frac{\ln (t)+\ln \left (\frac{a+b}{ab}\right )}{t^2+1}\ dt\\\\$$

$$ \frac{1}{ab(a+b)}\int_{\frac{ab(a+1)}{a+b}}^{\frac{ab(b+1)}{a+b}}\frac{\ln (t)+\ln \left (\frac{a+b}{ab}\right )}{t^2+1}\ dt\\\\$$

Again applying substitution $t\ =\dfrac{1}{u}$

$$ \frac{-1}{ab(a+b)}\int_{\frac{a+b}{ab(a+1)}}^{\frac{a+b}{ab(b+1)}}\frac{-\ln (u)+\ln \left (\frac{a+b}{ab}\right )}{u^2+1}\ du\\\\$$

Comment: Should the denominator have $(a+b)^2$? Otherwise, the first step of your attempt is wrong.

Comment: If we put $a=2$ and $b=3$, the integrand is positive in $[a,b]$. But the RHS is negative. It seems that this statement is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating your steps for the antiderivarive ( assuming $a>0$ and $b >0$)$$\int\frac{\log (1+x)}{a^2b^2(1+x)^2+({a+b})}\, dx=\frac 1{a^2\,b^2}\int\frac{\log (1+x)}{(1+x)^2+k^2}\, dx$$ with $k=\sqrt{\frac {a+b}{a^2\,b^2}}$ Now, let $r$ and $s$ be the complex roots of the denominator and use
$$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2+k^2}=\frac 1{(x-r)(x-s)}=\frac 1{r-s}\Big[\frac{1}{x-r}-\frac{1}{x-s} \Big]$$ So, we face two integrals
$$I_t=\int \frac{\log(1+x)}{x-t}\,dx=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x+1}{t+1}\right)+\log (x+1) \log
   \left(\frac{t-x}{t+1}\right)$$ Thsi would lead to much complex formulae for the definite integral (in which will remain logarithms, polylogarithms (with complex arguments) and  arctangents). If I am not mistaken, $\log(a+b)$ would never appear.

Answer (score 0):

By using integration by parts,
Differentiating ln(1+x) and integrating the remaining function gives an inverse tangent function integral in second part ,now set 1+x =z×(a+b)/ab  this substitution reduces the second integral to integration of arctan(z)/z under respective limits and observe that this integral is solvable by feynman parameter or integral under differential sign.

Comment: Sounds like an excellent idea! Could you possibly type it up using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: How did you get rid of the polylogarithms ?